# Running Typescript nodes application in Docker

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose

I have a TS application where I am trying to use docker to work on. I have my application running locally. I have added Docker file and docker-compose but I run into this error when running docker-compose up.

> Attaching to delivery-service delivery-service    | yarn run v1.22.10
> delivery-service    | $ node ./dist/server delivery-service    |
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638 delivery-service    |     throw
> err; delivery-service    |     ^ delivery-service    |
> delivery-service    | Error: Cannot find module '/app/dist/server'
> delivery-service    |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15) delivery-service    |     at
> Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
> delivery-service    |     at Function.Module.runMain
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12) delivery-service    |     at
> startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19) delivery-service    |
> at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
> delivery-service    | error Command failed with exit code 1.
> delivery-service    | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run
> for documentation about this command.

This is my docker file and my docker compose

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:10 as Base

WORKDIR /delivery-service

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN apk add --no-cache make gcc g++ python

RUN yarn

COPY . .

RUN yarn build:tsc

FROM mhart/alpine-node:10

WORKDIR /delivery-service

COPY --from=Base /delivery-service .

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

Docker compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  delivery-service:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    container_name: delivery-service
    ports:
      - "3006:3006"
    restart: always
    environment:
      PORT: 3006
      WORKER_PORT: 3011
      NODE_ENV: development
      MONGODB_URL: mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@xxxxxx.mongodb.net/yyyy?retryWrites=true&w=majority
      AMQP_URL: amqps://ccccc:xxxxx@abcc.rmq.cloudamqp.com/ttttt
```

My Package JSON

{
"name": "delivery-service",
"version": "1.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"description": "Blah blah.",
"scripts": {
"start": "node ./dist/server",
"start:worker": "node ./dist/server/workers/index",
"start:dev": "nodemon ./dist/server | bunyan",
"start:debug": "nodemon --inspect ./dist/server | bunyan",
"watch:tsc": "tsc --watch -p ./tsconfig.json",
"build:tsc": "tsc -p ./tsconfig.json",
...........

and my TS config

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2017",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["es2017", "esnext.asynciterable", "dom"],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "strict": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
            "@app/common/*": ["common/*"],
            "@app/data/*": ["data/*"],
            "@app/server/*": ["server/*"]
        },
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./typings"],
        "types": ["reflect-metadata", "node", "jest"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    },
    "exclude": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
    "include": ["typings/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*"]
}
```

folder hierarchy is

- Main Folder

  - dist

    - server

      - app.js
  - node_modules
  - src
  - Dockerfile
  - docker-compose.yml
  - tsconfig.json